# Achieving Concurrency and Parallelism in Java 7

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing

As part of a study I am doing, I am exploring the supposed simplicity of using languages like Scala & Clojure to achieve concurrency on the JVM.
By simplicity, I am hoping to prove that these languages provide easier concurrency constructs than what Java 7 provides.

Therefore, I am hoping to find some good references that explain the complexities of Java's concurrency model.

Outside of pointing me in the direction of Google (which I have already searched with limited success), I would appreciate if those in-the-know could provide me with some good references to get me started off in this area.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read this yet? http://rsim.cs.illinois.edu/Pubs/popl05.pdf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810692/looking-for-modern-java-threading-concurrent-programming-book

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support lambda expressions.  Creating an inline callback (eg, for the completion of an asynchronous call) requires 5 lines of boilerplate for an anonymous type.

This strongly discourages people from using callbacks.  This is probably why Java 7 still does not have an interface for a callback that takes a value (as opposed to `Runnable` and `Callbable`), whereas C# has had one [since 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Therefore, the JDK does not have any real support for asynchronous operations.
The key to an asynchronous operation is the ability to kick off a long-running request, and have it run a callback when it finishes, without consuming a thread for the duration of the request.  In Java, you can only do this by making a separate thread call `get()` on a `Future<V>`.  This limits the concurrency of an application using the standard API to the number of threads you can sanely support.

To solve this problem, Google's Guava framework for better Java code introduces a [`ListenableFuture<V>` interface](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) which does have completion callbacks.

Languages like Scala fix this problem by supporting lambda expressions (which [compile to anonymous classes](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-4-c.html)) and adding their own [Promise](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Promise) / [Future](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/future) types.

Comment: I don't think that's relevant to the question though.

Comment: @Antimony: Wait until I finish.

Answer (score 1):

While higher level languages are easier to use multiple cores, what is often forgotten is why you want to use multiple cores which is to make the program faster e.g. increase its throughput.

When you consider options which increase concurrency, you need to test whether these options actually improve performance in some way. (Because very often they don't)

e.g. STM (Software Transactional Memory) makes it easier to write multi-threaded applications without having to worry about concurrency issues.  The problem is that for trivial examples, it would be faster to not use STM and only use one thread.

Using multiple threads adds complexity and makes your application more fragile, so there has to be a good reason to do it otherwise you should stick to the simplest solution possible.

For more discussion
http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/why-concurency-examples-are-confusing.html